# differences between node and nodemon for express 4 project

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I've migrated from ES 6 import, export, to CommonJS Module, before my package.json script section  was :

```
   "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./src/server.js --inspect --exec babel-node -e js"
```

and now:

```
   "start": "NODE_ENV=development node ./src/server.js"
```

and all is working well and fast, but what does " --inspect --exec babel-node -e js" is just for nodemon?
I'm using node8 and it works really well for all my es6, es2017, without import/export. I really don't it need anymore. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--inspect` is for debugging purpose,whereas the `--exec babel-node` command is for starting the app in development mode (letting Babel interpret ES6 code).

**Nodemon** is a daemon to watch for file change and restart the server.

For more details read:

- [Debugging](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)
- [Nodemon and babel](https://gist.github.com/samuele-artuso/d39dc04650f9455e34549841a8270c82)

Hope this helps.

Comment: but --inspect and --exec babel-node , is useful only for nodemon? or for node too ?

Comment: Its useful for debugging in development mode.

Node and Nodemon are just the way to start the server. You can use it if you need it. Optional you can say.

Comment: what about babel? i do'nt really anymore i think

Comment: Depends on your requirement.
Was above content helpful?

Comment: thanks but looks --exec babel-node is ignored with node, it's just useful for nodemon, can you confirm it ?